# Subset a data.frame into a list in a more efficient way

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with 2 columns representing interaction between 2 genes. An example of how looks the data.frame:

```
head(df)
V1       V2
A1BG     A1BG
A1BG    CRISP3
A1CF     A1CF
A1CF   APOBEC1
A1CF    CUGBP2
A1CF     KHSRP
```

I want to split the data.frame based on values from first column, I've used the following command:

```
out <- split(df, df$V1)
```

The desired output should be:

```
out
$A1BG
[1] A1BG CRISP3

$A1CF
[2] A1CF APOBEC1 CUGBP2 KHSRP
```

However, the process using split takes such a long time since my file is too big (around 200,000 rows)

Many thanks

Comment: Make sure your columns aren't factors. Load your file or create your data.frame with the parameter `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. Then do: `split(df$V2, df$V1)`. It should be fast. I tried on a 1e5 data.frame and it finishes in 0.07 seconds.

Comment: @Arun the difference is that you are using `split.default` whereas `split.data.frame` is called for the OP's data. Internally, `split.default` has to create a factor if `f` isn't one so I don't see how it can be faster when providing a non-factor `f`.

Comment: When I try this character takes longer than factor in both cases: `char <-  rep(c("a", "b"), each = 10000);
fac <- factor(char);
library(rbenchmark);
benchmark(split(char, char), split(fac, fac));
DF.char <- data.frame(char, stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
DF.fac <- data.frame(fac);
benchmark(split(DF.char, char), split(DF.fac, fac))`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Nope, I don't think this has anything to do with factor `f`, which is what Arun was suggesting.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Indeed. `split.default` coerces `f` to factor if it isn't already one.

Comment: @Arun, your approach works very fast, I think my mistake was split(df, df$V2) instead of split(df$V1, df$V2). Thanks :-)

Comment: @GavinSimpson, my observation was that if `V2` was factor, then `split` is slow. IIUC, `split` will create factor on `V1`, not `V2`. Try `system.time(split(df$V2, df$V1))` on these two data.frames: `df <- data.frame(V1=sample(1e4, 1e5, replace=TRUE), V2=sample(letters, 1e5, replace=TRUE))` and `df <- data.frame(V1=sample(1e4, 1e5, replace=TRUE), V2=sample(letters, 1e5, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`...

Comment: @Arun I did, and the `stringsAsFactors` one was 50% slower! Just read the code for `split.default` and you'll see what you claim *can't* be right. If `f` is not a factor it is coerced to one. That extract step *can't* happen in negative time.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, I'm not talking about `f` being a factor. I agree with you in that regard. What I'm trying to say is, if `x` is a factor, `split` is SLOWER, whether `f` is a factor or not. Maybe I can write an answer to show what I'm talking about and delete after?

Comment: @GavinSimpson, I've created a temporary answer to show what I was talking about. I'll delete it soon after you have had a chance to look at it and tell if I've not understood your point still...

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, change your `char` to `char <- rep(1:1e4, each = 10)` and run again. As the number of levels in `x` increase, `as.factor(f)` seems to be *very* negligible. When `x` has very few levels, you see a slight edge when using `f` as a factor because it saves you `as.factor(f)`. What I was suggesting was actually for the OP to not use `x` as factor.

Comment: @Arun I see what you mean now - it was totally unclear that you were referring to the variable to be split in your original comment. Your follow-up comment used data with `x` and `y` but showed usage code with `df$V1` and `df$V2` without indication as to which was `x` and `y`. I think I must have tested the opposite of what you did. Hence I fully agree that argument `x`, if a factor, is not as quick as non-factor `x`. I thought we were discussing argument `f`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To speed this up, especially if you only need `df$V2` split apart on the basis of `df$V1`, use only that vector in the call to `split` not the entire data frame `df`. E.g:

```
## Dummy data
df <- read.table(text = "V1       V2
A1BG     A1BG
A1BG    CRISP3
A1CF     A1CF
A1CF   APOBEC1
A1CF    CUGBP2
A1CF     KHSRP", header = TRUE)
## make it big!
df <- with(df, cbind.data.frame(V1 = rep(V1, length.out = 1e5),
                                V2 = rep(V2, length.out = 1e5)))
# time it
system.time(sp1 <- split(df, df$V1))

system.time(sp2 <- split(df$V2, df$V1))

> system.time(sp1 <- split(df, df$V1))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.024   0.000   0.016 
> system.time(sp2 <- split(df$V2, df$V1))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.000   0.005
```

This is on an example with few levels though. With very many levels, the inefficiency of splitting the entire data frame starts to weigh heavily on compute time, e.g. for a factor with around 10000 levels:

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(sample(10000, 1e5, replace = TRUE)),
                  V2 = rnorm(1e5))

system.time(sp3 <- split(df2, df2$V1))

system.time(sp4 <- split(df2$V2, df2$V1))

> system.time(sp3 <- split(df2, df2$V1))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.332   0.000   4.216 
> 
> system.time(sp4 <- split(df2$V2, df2$V1))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.000   0.005
```

The reason for this is that in the `split(df, df$V1)` case, the `split.data.frame` method is called, which does an `lapply()` on a vector `1:nrow(df)` itself split into groups by `f` (`df$V2`), and applies a function (`function(ind) x[ind, , drop = FALSE])`) to each component. Hence as the number of levels grows large, the number of function calls to that anonymous function grows and inflates the compute time.

In the `split(df$V2, df$v1)` case the `split.default` method is used, which if called with factor `f` essentially only needs to call the fast C implementation of `split`. As such it doesn't incur any of the overhead of calling the anonymous function nor the repeated calls to `[`.